# cbind a column containing lists maintaining column of lists

Tags: r

I am trying to `cbind` a dataframe to a column, where some of the rows of that column are made up of lists. For example:

```
df1 <- tibble(x1=c(1,2,3))
df2 <- tibble(x2=c(4,5,6),
              x.list=list(list(7,8),9,list(10,11,12)))
```

But when I try to cbind just the column of lists:

```
df3 <- cbind(df1,df2$x.list)
```

I get an unnested(?) version of `xlist`:

```
7:30:10> df3
  x1 7 8 9 10 11 12
1  1 7 8 9 10 11 12
2  2 7 8 9 10 11 12
3  3 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

How can I cbind the column of lists and maintain it as a single column of lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this based on the deference between `$` and `[` where the later returns a `list`

```
df3 <- cbind(df1,df2[2])
```

- output

```
  x1     x.list
1  1       7, 8
2  2          9
3  3 10, 11, 12
```

we can see that `class(df3$x.list)` is `list`

Comment: That did it! I didn't realize $ and [ returns different classes. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend this for more information about [indexing in `R`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing)